# JADE : Can't generate mixin with an array

Tags: node.js, pug

I try to generate a code from a mixin which use an array :

```
- var tabList = [
    {
        data: "data-toggle",
        href: "#pp",
        text: "All"
    },{
        data: "data-toggle",
        href: "#pp",
        text: "Popol"
    }
];


mixin generateTabs(tabs)
    h1 tabs
        ul
            each tab in tabs
                li=tab.text


 +generateTabs(tabList)
```

When I try to compile it I have

```
dev\jade\test.jade:2
    1|     - var tabList = [
  > 2|         {
    3|             data: "data-toggle",
    4|             href: "#pp",
    5|             text: "All"

unexpected text {
```

I'm using Node 6.3.1, gulp-jade 1.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it right, you have to use a proper indentation.

```
-
 var tabList = [
    {
        data: "data-toggle",
        href: "#pp",
        text: "All"
    },{
        data: "data-toggle",
        href: "#pp",
        text: "Popol"
    }
 ];


mixin generateTabs(tabs)
    h1 tabs
        ul
            each tab in tabs
                li=tab.text


+generateTabs(tabList)
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEMJOL)